# How to implement dao to get list without createCriteria() and get list with following properties?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, deprecated, createcriteria

I am implementing DAO in Spring-5, Maven Project with Hibernate 5, for getting list with offset and maxcount with the help of 
 `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria()` but its now deprecated and i want to implement

I want these three function to be in new method for what `createCiteria()` replaced

```
@Override
public List<Department> list(Integer offset, Integer maxResults) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Department.class)
                .setFirstResult(offset!=null?offset:0)
                .setMaxResults(maxResults!=null?maxResults:10)
                .addOrder(Order.asc("department_name"))
                .list();
}
```

AND

```
@Override
public Long count() {
    return (Long)session.openSession()
            .createCriteria(Department.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
            .uniqueResult();
}
```

AND With Restrictions.eq()

```
@Override
public List<Department> getAllDepartmentsByDepartmentTypeId(int department_type_id) {   
    return session.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Department.class)
            .addOrder(Order.asc("department_name"))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("department_type_id", department_type_id))
            .list();
}
```

I want these three method to be implemented so that 
i can use instead of deprecated createCriteria() method

Answer (score 1):

Use [javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) instead and re-create your query with

```
builder.createQuery(...)
```

[Examples](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-criteria-query-example) can be found [all over](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) the [place](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries).